# Duvida ao usar SESSION para armazenar dados

Tags: php, session

Estou tentando exibir n nomes de uma lista, estou fazendo o uso de sessions para que isso seja possível.Quando utilizo a session por meio da pagina do formulário os elementos são adicionados n vezes ao array, no entanto quando faço o uso do mesmo pela classe não é me retornado o resultado esperado, queria saber aonde estou errando.

Obrigado desde já.

**form.php**

```
<?php
        include "Livro.class.php";  

        if($_POST){
            $livro = new Livro;

            // SESSÃO
            if(empty( $_SESSION['books'])){
                $_SESSION['books'] = [];
            }

            array_push($_SESSION['books'], [$_POST['name']]);

            // CLASSE
            $livro->add($_POST['name']);


            // OUTPUT
            echo "Da classe: <br>";
            var_dump($livro->livros);
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Da sessão: <br>";
            var_dump($_SESSION['books']);
        }
?>

<form action="#" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Livro.class.php**

```
<?php

class Livro 
{
    public $livros;

    function __construct(){
        session_start(); 

        if(empty($_SESSION['livros']))
            $_SESSION['livros'] = [];

        $this->livros = $_SESSION['livros'];
    }

    function add($nome){
        array_push($this->livros, [$nome]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você não está atualizando o valor da session na sua classe, veja a correção no metodo "add"

```
<?php

class Livro 
{
    public $livros;

    function __construct(){
        session_start(); 

        if(empty($_SESSION['livros']))
            $_SESSION['livros'] = [];

        $this->livros = $_SESSION['livros'];
    }

    function add($nome){
        array_push($this->livros, [$nome]);

        $_SESSION['livros'] = $this->livros;
    }

}

?>
```